# Is there a way to insert a certain amount of rows below a row that contains certain criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that contains data starting in row 2 column 1 and has 42 columns. I am trying to write a VBA code that will search all rows of my data starting with row 2 and if the value in column 32 is greater than 575, I need the code to insert enough rows below that row so that whatever the value was (whether it be 600 or 2,000) can be split into increments of 575. So for example, if row 5 column 32's value is 800, i want the code to add a row below row 5, and i want it to autofill the new row with the value of 575 in column 32 and replace the value in the original row with whatever it was minus 575. Also, in the first column of my data I have dates. For each new row that is created, I want it to be a week earlier than the date in the original row. Here is an example of what my data looks like:

Column1 ...Column 32.......Column 42

8/15/2019 // 3873

Here is what i want it to look like after I run the code.

Column1 ...Column 32......Column 42

8/15/2019 //  423

8/8/2019  //  575

8/1/2019 //   575

7/25/2019  // 575

7/18/2019  // 575

7/11/2019  // 575

7/4/2019   // 575

The slash marks are just there to show the separation in columns. And I want the data from all the other columns to stay the same as the row above. Is there a good way to do this?

This is the code I've come up with so far. However, the problem with it is I can't seem to figure out how to program it so that it know how many rows to add based on how large the quantity is. As of now, it just adds a row below any row that the value of column 32 is greater than 575. Also, it just adds blank rows. I don't have anything in my code that says what values to put in the newly created rows

```
Sub BlankLine()

Dim Col As Variant
Dim BlankRows As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim LargeOrder As Integer

    Col = "AF"
    StartRow = 1
    BlankRows = 1
    LargeOrder = 575

        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        With ActiveSheet
        For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(R, Col).Value > LargeOrder Then
        .Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
        Next R
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        End Sub
```

As I mentioned before, I need the code to add however many rows needed to accommodate the original quantity to be broken into increments of 575, and also subtract a week with every row created. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous way to achieve the objective. One is instead of reverse loop, you go down inserting balance amount and again on next row recalculated and so on till blank is encounters. May try the code tested with makeshift data

```
Option Explicit
Sub addLine()
Dim Col As Variant
'Dim BlankRows As Long
'Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim LargeOrder As Integer

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim ActNum As Double, Balance As Double
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Col = "AF"
StartRow = 2
'BlankRows = 1
LargeOrder = 575

R = StartRow
  With Ws
  ActNum = .Cells(R, Col).Value
    Do While ActNum <> 0
        If ActNum > LargeOrder Then
        .Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        .Range(.Cells(R, 1), .Cells(R, 42)).Copy Destination:=.Cells(R + 1, 1)
        .Cells(R + 1, 1).Value = .Cells(R + 1, 1).Value - 7
         'simpler calculation 
         Balance = IIf(ActNum Mod LargeOrder > 0, Int(ActNum / LargeOrder) * LargeOrder, ActNum - LargeOrder)
        'Balance = IIf(ActNum Mod LargeOrder > 0, Int(ActNum / LargeOrder) * LargeOrder, Int(ActNum / LargeOrder) * LargeOrder - LargeOrder)
        .Cells(R + 1, Col).Value = Balance
        .Cells(R, Col).Value = ActNum - Balance
        End If
    R = R + 1
    ActNum = .Cells(R, Col).Value
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

Edit: may try the modified code below for the variance in requirement

```
Option Explicit
Sub addLine2()
Dim Col As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long, i As Long
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim RowtoAdd As Long

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim ActNum As Double, Balance As Double
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Col = "AS"
StartRow = 2
LastRow = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

R = StartRow
  With Ws

    Do
    RowtoAdd = .Cells(R, Col).Value
    LastRow = LastRow + RowtoAdd
        For i = 1 To RowtoAdd
        .Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        .Cells(R, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=.Cells(R + 1, 1)
        .Cells(R + 1, 1).Value = .Cells(R + 1, 1).Value - 7
        .Cells(R + 1, 32).Value = ""
        R = R + 1
        Next i
    R = R + 1
    Loop Until R > LastRow
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code and when I ran it, nothing happened. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I'm very new to macros.

Comment: Pl check if `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` column AF has data started from row 2

Comment: Also it assumed that Col AF has non zero positive whole numbers. Zero at any row will end the loop.

Comment: It does. Should i change "ActiveSheet" to the name of the actual sheet?

Comment: Yes obviously.Pl change similar   Range & sheets related parameters to your requirement. add a line `Msgbox ActNum` after line `ActNum = .Cells(R, Col).Value` and feedback.

Comment: Col AF does have a few numbers that fall between 0 and 1, like 0.5. How should i change the code to accomodate that

Comment: Just change `Dim ActNum As Double, Balance As Double` (tested again with changed declaration and found working correct)  instead of Long.that will accommodate fraction but certainly 0 would end the loop.

Comment: Welcome,  you made my day.

Comment: So i need to make a change. Instead of adding rows when the quantity in column 32>575, i need the code to add rows when the value in column 45>0, and whatever that value is, thats how many rows i want to add. the majority of the values in column 45 are zeros, so i want the code to pick out the non-zero values and add that many rows beneath the row that contains that value. And i still want the date to go down by one week on every new row created. However, i now want column 32 in every new row to be blank and i want everything else from the row above copied down into the new row. Can you help?

Comment: Would you be willing to take a look at the new question I posted today? You seem to really know what you are doing